# Using a Form With Variables as Part of a Function

Tags: php

Could the form below be part of a function?  I am wondering if it might not be able to be part of a function since it has variables.

Thanks in advance,

John

```
echo '<form  action="http://www...com/sandbox/comments/comments2.php" method="post"> 
    <input type="hidden" value="'.$_SESSION['loginid'].'" name="uid">
    <input type="hidden" value="'.$submissionid.'" name="submissionid">  
    <input type="hidden" value="'.$submission.'" name="submission">
    <input type="hidden" value="'.$url.'" name="url">
    <input type="hidden" value="'.$submittor.'" name="submittor">
    <input type="hidden" value="'.$submissiondate.'" name="submissiondate">
    <input type="hidden" value="'.$countcomments.'" name="countcomments">
    <input type="hidden" value="'.$dispurl.'" name="dispurl">



    <label class="addacomment" for="title">Add a comment:</label>

    <textarea class="commentsubfield" name="comment" type="comment" id="comment" maxlength="1000"></textarea>  

    <div class="commentsubbutton"><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"></div> 
</form>
';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use that code in a function provided that:

- You pass those parameters ($submissionid, $submission etc) to the function

or

- You make them global (**you shouldn't do this without strong reason**)

Answer (score 0):

There's three basic choices for passing form arguments into a function:

1. massive argument list
2. stuff the values into an array and passing that in
3. global variables

Generally only #2 will keep your hair from getting yanked out (by yourself or other people). The basic setup would go something like:

```
function show_form($args) {
    echo <<<EOL
<form action="yada yada">
    <input type="..." name="field1" values="{$args['field1']}" />
    <input type="..." name="field2" values="{$args['field2']}" />
    etc...
</form>
EOL;
}

$form_args = array(
    'field1' => $field1,
    'field2' => $field2,
    etc...
)

show_form($form_args);
```

Note that I'm using a [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc) to generate the form text. It's far easier to deal with than building a string with concatenation. It saves you from having to worry about escaping quotes.

If this form deals with potentially hostile users, you'll want to pass all the values through [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) beforehand, to prevent some HTML injection attacks. You can do that within the form building function, or while you're building the argument array.

comment followup:

In this example, you're building array called "form_args" to store all the field data of your form. I'm just calling them "field1", "field2" etc... You pass those $form_args array as a parmeter to the show_form() function. Within the function, it accesses that data via its own private little "$args" copy of the array.

Within the form, the notation `{$args['field1']}` simply means "Look in the $args array for an entry whose key is 'field1', and insert its matching value into the HTML being generated here. The braces (`{}`) aren't strictly necessary in this case, but could be considered good practice to use anyways. There's more details in the PHP online manual's [Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) entry

Comment: Okay, thanks.  I'm a little confused by what I should use for "$args" and "{$args['field1']}", {$args['field2']}, etc.  Can you provide me with some guidance on that?